# Reading BLE devices properly in the scan result on android studio

Tags: java, android, android-studio, bluetooth, bluetooth-lowenergy

I am following a nordic open source example to build a BLE app for scanning and connecting to a nordic chip. However, the scanning result does not make much sense to me.

I used the Android studio emulator and the result shows like this:
[image]

I am not sure what beac,gbea are because I turned off my surrounding devices (e.g., phone and my computer bluetooth). The MAC address does not relate to any of my devices either.

The code I have is:

```
/**
 * Start scanning for Bluetooth devices.
 */
public void startScan() {
    if (scannerStateLiveData.isScanning()) {
        return;
    }

    // Scanning settings
    final ScanSettings settings = new ScanSettings.Builder()
            .setScanMode(ScanSettings.SCAN_MODE_LOW_LATENCY)
            .setReportDelay(500)
            .setUseHardwareBatchingIfSupported(false)
            .build();

    final BluetoothLeScannerCompat scanner = BluetoothLeScannerCompat.getScanner();
    scanner.startScan(null, settings, scanCallback);
    scannerStateLiveData.scanningStarted();
}
```

I also tried the following to hope to see the name of surrounding devices (my phone) but it does not appear to have anything showed up:

```
String[] names = new String[]{"Polar H7 391BB014"};
ScanSettings settings = new ScanSettings.Builder()
        .setScanMode(ScanSettings.SCAN_MODE_LOW_POWER)
        .setCallbackType(ScanSettings.CALLBACK_TYPE_ALL_MATCHES)
        .setMatchMode(ScanSettings.MATCH_MODE_AGGRESSIVE)
        .setNumOfMatches(ScanSettings.MATCH_NUM_ONE_ADVERTISEMENT)
        .setReportDelay(0L)
        .build();
List<ScanFilter> filters = null;
if(names != null) {
    filters = new ArrayList<>();
    for (String name : names) {
        ScanFilter filter = new ScanFilter.Builder()
                .setDeviceName(name)
                .build();
        filters.add(filter);
    }
}
final BluetoothLeScannerCompat scanner = BluetoothLeScannerCompat.getScanner();
scanner.startScan(filters, settings, scanCallback);
```

I wonder can anyone explain how to I properly set up the BLE scan and it can see my surrounding device and that I can set up to see my nordic chip?

Thank you in advance

Comment: Just to be clear you are using a physical device to run the test and not the emulator as [Bluetooth isn't supported on emulator](https://developer.android.com/studio/run/emulator#limitations)

Comment: try to scan without settings and filters: scanner.startScan(callback)

Comment: @MorrisonChang Thanks for the response! I am using a Android studio emulator to run the source code and the picture is what I saw! You meant I can't do the scan/ connect testing using an emulator and I must have an android device? Thanks - I am a bit new to this.

Comment: @AnatoliiChub Thanks you the response! The results are the same. I am still seeing beac, gbea etc which still do not make sense to me...

Comment: @swiftlearneer Correct any real bluetooth work should be done with a device. Emulator may give dummy data for testing purposes. You should run your source code on a physical device.